# Get every control within android view to perform event on each one

Tags: android, layout

is there a way on android to collect all of the controls within an XML file for a layout, maybe adding them to an array and then looping through every control to perform a certain action.

For example, my main.xml layout file will contain a couple of input boxes. What I was hoping to do was add each of the input boxes automatically and pass the array onto another function. Then the function could loop through the array and do something with the controls i.e. clear the text in each edittext.

Is this at all possibble.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the parent ViewGroup and then use its `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt` methods to get all the child views of this ViewGroup.

For example:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_viewgroup);
List<View> childViews = new ArrayList<View>();
for(int count = 0; count < layout.getChildCount(); count ++) {
    childViews.add(layout.getChildAt(count));
}
```

You should then be able to pass the list to another method for further processing.

Comment: this does work, but if you have LinearLayout already which has the two methods you mentioned then you've already got a structure that you can iterate through (as you've shown with your for loop) I see no reason to put them into a List, just use them out of the LinearLayout via getChildAt() when you needto access them iteratively imo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. It is called "ListView".